# Hilbert space, does $|r\rangle$ satisfy $\langle r |r\rangle = 1$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, normalization

Let's say we start with no particles: $\mid0\rangle$. We have $\vec{p}\vert0\rangle = 0$, $H\vert0\rangle = 0$, where we are ignoring $\infty$ vacuum energy. Also, $a(\vec{k})\vert0\rangle = 0$ for all $\vec{k}$. The Hilbert space now splits into sectors of $r$ particle states, $r = 0$, $1$, $2, \dots$. A general $r$ particle state has the form$$\vert r\rangle = {1\over{\sqrt{r! \int {{d^3 \vec{k}_1}\over{(2\pi)^3}} \dots  \int {{d^3 \vec{k}_r}\over{(2\pi)^3}} \left| F(\vec{k}_1, \dots, \vec{k}_r)\right|^2}}}$$$$\cdot \int {{d^3 \vec{k}_1}\over{(2\pi)^3}} \dots  \int {{d^3 \vec{k}_r}\over{(2\pi)^3}} F(\vec{k}_1, \dots, \vec{k}_r)\, a^\dagger (\vec{k}_1) \dots a^\dagger(\vec{k}_r) \,\vert0\rangle.$$My question is, must $\vert r\rangle$ necessarily satisfy $\langle r\, \vert  \,r \rangle = 1$?

Comment: If the question is: *"must one include the normalisation factor?"* the answer is no, one does not necessarily have to.

Comment: No, if you define the expectation values on a vector $|r\rangle$ as $\operatorname{EXP}[O] := \frac{\langle r|O|r\rangle}{\langle r|r\rangle}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no, the normalization condition is not always necessary." I think this really depends on how do you use that normalization condition. You can always make a state normalized to 1 as you have correctly stated. But that condition can be arbitrarily chosen for different purposes. For example, a [coherent state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states), $|\alpha\rangle$, satisfies $\hat{a}|\alpha\rangle=\alpha|\alpha\rangle$ and $⟨\alpha|\alpha⟩=e^{|\alpha|^2-\alpha^2}$, which is referred to ***overcomplete***-basis state. This definition is useful when considering a laser field with uncertain photon numbers, and $\alpha$ is measure of photon statistical properties.

Does this answer your question?